# Flask App with Dockerfile on Heroku Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: python, docker, heroku, gitlab-ci

when I deployed with Docker to Heroku my flask app it errors out with the error message:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "run:app"]
```

Here is the content of gunicorn_config.py:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 4
threads = 4
timeout = 120
```

Here is script commands I use in my gitlab-ci:

```
script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
    - docker tag  $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$IMAGE_NAME:latest registry.heroku.com/my-app/web
    - docker login --username=_ --password=$HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com
    - docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app/web
    - docker run --rm -e HEROKU_API_KEY=$HEROKU_API_KEY wingrunr21/alpine-heroku-cli container:release web --app my-app
    - echo "App deployed to server at https://my-app.herokuapp.com/"
```

Until this point everything is successful. I am able to deploy to Heroku.

But when I try to open the app it is crashed. With this command, I see the logs - Heroku logs --tail

```
Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-04-01T06:23:03.125358+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:03 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-04-01T06:23:03.125467+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-04-01T06:23:03.125524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-04-01T06:23:03.131769+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:03 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-04-01T06:23:03.326507+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:03 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-04-01T06:23:03.518148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-04-01T06:23:06.918424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --config gunicorn_config.py run:app`
2022-04-01T06:23:07.717472+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-04-01T06:23:07.717835+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4)
2022-04-01T06:23:07.717884+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2022-04-01T06:23:07.720605+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2022-04-01T06:23:07.727693+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2022-04-01T06:23:07.776540+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2022-04-01T06:23:07.848862+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:23:07 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-04-01T06:24:07.069895+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-04-01T06:24:07.138987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-04-01T06:24:07.316175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-04-01T06:24:07.373029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-04-01T06:24:07.445856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-04-01T06:24:13.147942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn --config gunicorn_config.py run:app`
2022-04-01T06:24:14.202704+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-04-01T06:24:14.203085+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4)
2022-04-01T06:24:14.203129+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2022-04-01T06:24:14.206105+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2022-04-01T06:24:14.239507+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2022-04-01T06:24:14.327054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2022-04-01T06:24:14.399461+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-04-01 06:24:14 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-04-01T06:25:13.653641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-04-01T06:25:13.690271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-04-01T06:25:13.868500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-04-01T06:25:13.990309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It seems like the issue is has something to do with the PORT, but I have it set in the gunicorn_config.py file to be 5000. It even prints in the logs that it is listening at port 5000 Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4).

Perhaps someone can see where is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following gunicorn config:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:" + os.getenv("PORT")
workers = 4
threads = 4
timeout = 120
```

Comment: Thanks! I just removed gunicorn config file and changed my CMD command to:
CMD [ "gunicorn", "run:app", "--bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT"]
The truth is that I used gunicorn config file without really knowing if other options are needed. If it runs only with PORT it is enough for me :D Although it still puzzles me in which step does Heroku apply the PORT and how they decide which PORT to use

Comment: The URL is resolved to an ip address and port. Heroku hosts multiple apps under a single ip address. This would break immediately if everyone was using the standard ports. That's why the port cannot be firmly set by the user and is random. It shouldn't affect you anyway because you just input your website URL and don't need the port anymore. It gets automatically resolved for you.